# How to implement fileSystemProvider API onReadFileRequested listener?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement a fileSystemProvider for Chrome OS.

I'm stuck on the onReadFileRequested event.

The documentation is here:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystemProvider#event-onReadFileRequested

I've also seen the two samples:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:onreadfilerequested

My first question is what is the point of hasMore? In both examples it's hard set to false. In my case I need to async download chunks. If I set hasMore to true it just hangs. If I set hasMore to false, it loops to the next byte range. What?

So with hasMore set to false, it seems to iterate over the byte ranges just fine except...I don't know how to make it stop. Eventually my logic requests an invalid byte range prompting my API to return a 416 error, stopping the loop. The file is all there, but the Files app shows an error. How do I stop it from looping even though hasMore is false? Is there a set number of iterations based on file length?

Here's my code. I'm using jQuery to make the ajax request with a custom ajaxTransport to handle the ArrayBuffer type.

ajaxTransport:

```
$.ajaxTransport("+binary", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){
    if (window.FormData &&
        ((options.dataType && (options.dataType === 'binary')) ||
         (options.data && ((window.ArrayBuffer && options.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) ||
                           (window.Blob && options.data instanceof Blob))))) {
        return {
            send: function(_, callback){
                console.log(callback);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    url = options.url,
                    type = options.type,
                    dataType = options.responseType || "blob",
                    data = options.data || null;
                xhr.addEventListener('load', function(){
                    var data = {};
                    data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
                    callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                });
                xhr.open(type, url, true);
                for (var key in options.headers) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(key, options.headers[key]);
                }
                xhr.responseType = dataType;
                xhr.send(data);
            },
            abort: function(){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

listener:

```
function readFile(options, successCallback, errorCallback){
    var filePath = opened_files[options.openRequestId];
    client.readFile(filePath, options.offset, options.length, function(data, hasMore){
        successCallback(data, hasMore);
    }, errorCallback);
}
```

readFile function:

```
readFile: function(filePath, offset, length, successCallback, errorCallback){
    var url = <api_url> + filePath;
    $.ajax(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {"Range": "bytes=" + offset + "-" + (offset + length -1)},
        dataType: "binary",
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        success: function(dataBuffer){
            successCallback(dataBuffer, false);
        },
        error: function(err){
            errorCallback();
        }
    });
},
```

**EDIT:** I've taken into consideration some of the comments below but still have not made progress. It seems I have yet to fully understand what makes the onReadFile stop iterating and asking for more chunks. I've also noticed that the progress bar never goes up. options.length is always the same value as well.

Comment: You return all the data you fetch with ajax in one call so hasMore should be false because there's no more in the requested range. When hasMore is true Chrome continues to schedule a new task, and your code never sets hasMore to false, which leads to an infinite loop. This is working according to spec. As for why it continues to the next range, try debugging: maybe there's an off-by-1 error in the offset or length.

Comment: I think that makes sense in this context but what is telling chrome to request the next range?

I recognize that this is definitely the equivalent of an off by one error but I'm not quite sure how to identify when to stop and how to properly manipulate the range without manually parsing the content length header. Chrome seems to know there's more to the file, but there's no like "filesize" property in the options of the request.

Comment: It seems like unless I call errorCallback, it will just continue to increase the offset and ask for more. How do I tell it no you have everything and end successfully?

Comment: It looks like hasMore indicates the end. Also, this would probably be easier with [fetch and streams](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/#streams)

Comment: The ajax portion is not the problem. I'm now just simply stubbing out that call and returning an ArrayBuffer of the requested length from options.length. I'm noticing that the length is always the same, 524288, regardless of the file. My files are being listed with the correct file sizes in the files app though.

Comment: So far I've managed to hack something together by catching the error and calling successCallback one last time with a 0 length ArrayBuffer. Length is still always the same and the progress bar never fills up. I suppose it works though.